# Using information from .crs files and command line to make a template for an output file

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I want to sift through a `.crs` file using `bash`, and take the fields from the `.crs` file and put them in a template.

For example let's say this is a `.crs` file:

```
MAT Mathematics
TH 8/26/10 12/12/19
Data Analysis and Intepretation
60
```

I want to look at line 4. If that number is higher than 50, I want to create a template like so:

```
Hi your class [[className]] has [[numStudents]]. This is too many. It starts on [[startDate]] and ends on [[endDate]].
```

How would I tell bash that I want to take the first element of line 1 (MAT) and put it in place of `[[classCode]]` every time it is seen?

Comment: I rephrased with a more specific question

Comment: I find it really difficult to read this question. What the heck is a `.crs` file, Google says it's a Word Perfect document? If they are plain text, please include a sample *formatted as code*.  And what do you mean by "link the lines"?

Comment: I'll edit the original to try and make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

How about an `awk` program. Assuming the course information is always layouted as shown, and every CRS file has only one course information, the following will do:

```
awk 'FNR==1{class=$1}
     FNR==2{start=$2; end=$3}
     FNR==4{if ($1>50) printf("Your class %s has %d students. This is too many.\nIt starts on %s and ends on %s\n",class,$1,start,end)}' example.crs
```

This parses the file based on the line number (using `FNR` the internal per-file line-counter variable of `awk`) and hence relies on the exact structure you showed in the example. This also means that you can apply it to several files at once, as in

```
awk ' ... ' *.csr
```

if you have more than one course definition files in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
k=open('filename','r')
o=k.readlines()
u1=o[0].strip().split(' ')[0]
u2=o[1].strip().split(' ')
st= u2[1]
en= u2[2]

if (int(o[3].strip()) > 50):
        print "Hi your class {0} has {1}. This is too many. It starts on {2} and ends on {3}.".format(u1,o[3].strip(),st,en)
```

Tested and worked fine